# How to get $k^{k + 1} + k^k$ to equate $(k+1)^{k+1}$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

This is a problem from Discrete Mathematics and its Applications

> 18. Let $P(n)$ be the statement that $n!<n^n$, where $n$ is an integer greater than $1$.
>
> $\quad(a)$ What is the statement $P(2)$?
> $\quad(b)$ Show that $P(2)$ is true, completing the basis step of the proof.
> $\quad(c)$ What is the inductive hypothesis?
> $\quad(d)$ What do you need to prove in the inductive step?
> $\quad(e)$ Complete the inductive step.
> $\quad(f)$ Explain why these steps show that this inequality is true whenever $n$ is an integer greater than $1$.

I am currently on part e, completing the inductive step. 
Here is my work so far,

I was able to show that the basic step, $P(2)$ is true because $2! < 2^2$ or $2 < 4$
Now I am trying to show the inductive step, or $P(k)\to P(k+1)$
Assuming $P(k)$, $k! <k^k$, show $(k+1)! < (k+1)^{k+1}$
To get $(k+1)!$ on both sides, I multiplied both sides by $k +1$ to get
$$(k+1)! <  k^k(k+1)$$ or $$(k+1)! < k^{k + 1} + k^k$$

How can I get this expression,  $k^{k + 1} + k^k$ to equate $(k+1)^{k+1}$?

Comment: Should not have expanded. We have $(k^k)(k+1)\lt (k+1)^k(k+1)=(k+1)^{k+1}$.

Comment: You don't need to "equate", it is sufficient to establish that $k^{k+1} + k^k < (k+1)^{k+1}$

Comment: @DanielV wait how did you turn that screenshot to text content?

Comment: @committedandroider Mr. Scott did that (and well), and to see how he did it, click the edit button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$(n+1)!=(n+1) n! < (n+1) n^n<(n+1) (n+1)^n=(n+1)^{n+1} $$

Comment: Oh cause you know (n)$^n < (n+1)^n$? for integers > 1?

Answer (score 1):

You have 
$$k^{k+1} + k^k = k^k(k+1) $$

Can you use this fact?